# Is exportFormats from about.get() user dependent?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like my users to be able to chose the export format of their native Drive documents.

Ideally, i'd like the list of available export formats to be built dynamically using the `exportFormat` of the `About` resource, and built **before** the user is authenticated in Google Drive.

Obviously, if the `exportFormat` is user dependent (only reason i can see would be because of apps), I can't do what I want. But if it is not, I can get these information with my app authenticated in Google Drive.

As a side question, and if the answer to my main question is "no", is it possible to retrieve the export formats being unauthenticated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the list of available formats is independent of the user. They vary by file type --docs vs. presentations vs. spreadsheets etc will have different sets of supported formats.

For the 2nd question, it's not possible to retrieve that list anonymously.